# Null Pointer Exception with none of my code in logcat

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a NPE, but when I check the logcat there are no points at which it is using my code.

The program crashes after attempting to show an AlertDialog containing a RadioButtonGroup.  It previously worked and the only changes I remember are after the dialog.

Now I recieve the following:
**EDIT:**

```
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-19 17:15:19.430: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The last code block that is run, when I step through, is:

```
public void addTeam (View view) {
    //open select race dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 

    String[] items = new String[races.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Race race : races) {
        //add radio button for each race
        items[i] = race.raceName;
    }
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.select_race));
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, null);

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.done, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int whichButton) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                Team team = new Team();
                team.raceIndex = ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                team.raceName = races.get(team.raceIndex).raceName;
                setContentView(R.layout.edit_team);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.raceTV)).setText(team.raceName);
            }
    });

    alertDialog = builder.create();  
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Without a line reference to my code, I do not even know where to start.  Help is appreciated.

Comment: Moral of the story.  If your code is not in the stack trace, you may have sent out an improper variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an error in your code:

```
int i = 0;
for (Race race : races) {
    //add radio button for each race
    items[i] = race.raceName;
}
```

You don't increment `i` in the for loop.
May be this causes the crash.

Comment: Are you sure about that? If the array as a lenght greater than 1, only the first entry is not null and I think the adapter crashes when trying to access the second element

Comment: Thanx, fumble fingers cleaning up code, I guess, since it had worked before. I must have deleted the i++.

Comment: @Donkey Sorry, my mistake ! I did'nt see that the array was used in the builder. Nice catch =)

Answer (score 1):

You have two `dialog` instances. 1) `AlertDialog dialog;` and 2) `DialogInterface dialog`. So most probably `AlertDialog dialog;` throwing `NPE` as it was never initilized so defaluts to `null`

Comment: Yep. The reference to your code will be further down the stack trace.  `dialog` is null for sure.

Comment: That is the complete stack trace. Neither dialog was null, but edited variable names for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.raceTV)).setText(team.raceName);
```

with

```
((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.raceTV)).setText(team.raceName);
```